# GLSL: Unable to find compatible overloaded function

Tags: glsl

I am trying to write a fragment shader and I've hit a wall. This is only my second shader so I'm very new to this and I'm almost certain I'm just not dealing with the data types properly and that's where the error is coming from but for the life of me I can't seem to fix it. The goal is to be able to pass a texture to the function so I can call it again and again... Any and all help would be appreciated!

The error I get is: error C1115: unable to find compatible overloaded function "texture2D(vec3, vec2)".

```
uniform sampler2D image;
uniform float radius;
uniform float adsk_result_w, adsk_result_h;

vec2 iResolution = vec2(adsk_result_w, adsk_result_h);
vec2 uv=(gl_FragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy);
vec2 vTexCoord = (gl_FragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy);
float blurSize = radius/iResolution;

vec4 hblur(vec4 frontin ) {
    vec3 RTScene = frontin.rgb;
    vec4 sum = vec4(0.0);
    sum += texture2D(RTScene, vec2(vTexCoord.x - 4.0*blurSize, vTexCoord.y)) * 0.05;
    sum += texture2D(RTScene, vec2(vTexCoord.x - 3.0*blurSize, vTexCoord.y)) * 0.09;
    sum += texture2D(RTScene, vec2(vTexCoord.x - 2.0*blurSize, vTexCoord.y)) * 0.12;
    sum += texture2D(RTScene, vec2(vTexCoord.x - blurSize, vTexCoord.y)) * 0.15;
    sum += texture2D(RTScene, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y)) * 0.16;
    sum += texture2D(RTScene, vec2(vTexCoord.x + blurSize, vTexCoord.y)) * 0.15;
    sum += texture2D(RTScene, vec2(vTexCoord.x + 2.0*blurSize, vTexCoord.y)) * 0.12;
    sum += texture2D(RTScene, vec2(vTexCoord.x + 3.0*blurSize, vTexCoord.y)) * 0.09;
    sum += texture2D(RTScene, vec2(vTexCoord.x + 4.0*blurSize, vTexCoord.y)) * 0.05;
return vec4(sum);
}

void main() {
    vec4 front = texture2D(image, uv);
    vec4 work = hblur(front);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(work);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message tells you there is no `texture2D` overload that expects a `vec3` as first and a `vec2` as second argument. The first argument of `texture2D` has to be a of the type `sampler2D`.

Literally you tell OpenGL in your code with `texture2D(RTScene, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y))` to look for the color at position `vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y)` in the texture `RTScene`. But as `RTScene` is just a `vec3` containing three floats (the rgb value you retrieved in the `main`), where should OpenGL find the pixel.

In your main code you would have something like this:

```
vec4 work = hblur(image, uv);
```

And your `hblur` should look something like this:

```
vec4 hblur(sampler2D tex, vec2 uv) {
    // your other code
    sum += texture2D(tex, vec2(uv.x - 4.0*blurSize, uv.y)) * 0.05;
    // your other code
}
```

It is always helpful to look at the OpenGL Quick Reference Card for the OpenGL version your are coding for, there you will have a quick overview over the available functions:

- [OpenGL 3.2 API Reference Card](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengl-quick-reference-card.pdf)
- [OpenGL 4.1 API Reference Card](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengl41-quick-reference-card.pdf)
- [OpenGL 4.2 API Reference Card](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengl42-quick-reference-card.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much! That did the trick once I changed "sample2D" to "sampler2D". Many thanks!

Comment: @NumbThumb yes, sorry for the typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: I've got one last issue. When I try to pass that result to another function which is identical, but for the vertical pass, I'm getting an error about incompatible type of parameter "tex". I'm trying to do the following: vec4 pass1 = hblur(image, uv); vec4 pass2 = vblur(pass1, uv);

Comment: @NumbThumb because `pass1` is a `vec4` and not an `sampler2D`. When you want to do a gaussian blur you also need to do two passes first blur e.g. horizontal and then vertical or the other way round.

Comment: I figured as much, thank you. Maybe I'm making it more difficult on myself trying to do both passes in one shader. I suppose that isn't even possible. My logic was that I'd first do the horizontal blur, then the vertical and then run it through the horizontal and then vertical again to get a smoother results. Am I completely wrong in my thinking?

Comment: @NumbThumb At first: you should not start a new question as comment but create really a new one. To your second question: [GLSL - one-pass gaussian blur](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26649/glsl-one-pass-gaussian-blur)

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for all the help.